# Merge tags: [ipad-pro] and [ipadpro]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [ipadpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipadpro) should be renamed in [ipad-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad-pro) and used as synonym.

Comment: Can you provide a rationale for that change?

Comment: [tag:ipad-mini], [tag:ipad-2], [tag:ipad-3] ...

Comment: So it would be for consistency with the other tags? I don't know if that warrants a synonym, but considering the `[ios]` tag family, of which some have a hyphen but others do not, it may not be worth it.

Comment: I don't know about the iPad Pro to say definitively, but I speculate that the differences between this and existing iPads will be small enough that a new tag won't be required. I suggest "synonymising" `ipadpro` and `iPad-pro` to `iPad`

Comment: Since [tag:ipad-pro] has no questions, and [tag:ipadpro] has only one -- and that's yours -- why do you think a synonym is required? why don't you just retag the one question you made?

Comment: @TZHX: The system wrote that ipadpro already exists and I should create a post on meta if I want to use another one (ipad-pro).

Answer (score 5):

To maintain consistency with the other [ipad-*] tags, I've created [ipad-pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad-pro) and made [ipadpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipadpro) a synonym of it. Seeing as how your question was the one to introduce [ipadpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipadpro) (there were no previous questions in that tag), I'm not entirely sure as to why you didn't choose the other one to begin with. You should have been able to create it at the time you asked your question.

There's enough different in the hardware (the digitizer, the different GPU, etc.) that there possibly could be questions specific to this model of iPad, so I didn't see a need yet to direct it to the main iPad tag.

Comment: This. Whether it's in choosing the hyphenated tag to begin with, or to ask to have it fixed after realizing you screwed up, or to maintain a separate tag from the regular [ipad], I don't see how any of those things are a big deal.

Comment: I was not able to create the tag (ipad-pro). Perhaps there was a question before and it got deleted. I didn't create the ipadpro tag.

Comment: @BoltClock: I wanted to help to improve SO. But thats a big mistake. I won't make any requests in future. Waste of time.

Comment: So you'd rather let the resistance get to you even though we were more than glad to oblige you? OK then.