# Confusing warning/error messages when creating certain tags

Tags: bug, tags

When attempting to add the tag "ipad-pro" to a question, I get the warning:

> Are you sure you want to create new tags?
>
> The following tags do not exist: [ipad-pro].
>
> Did you intend to create these tags?

If I continue, then I get the error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [ipad-pro]; however the tag [ipad-pro] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

- Does the tag exist or not?
- If I'm not allowed to create it, then:

  - Why not say that, rather than stating that it already exists?
  - Why offer to create it in the first place?

Comment: Maybe it's blacklisted?

Comment: @rene Yeah. that's what it looks like. But if so, why not say so in the messages?

Comment: There is some earlier confusion about that tag [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305770/578411). Not sure what is causing that issue but I would blame Brad...